# Android app do something on close service/app

Tags: android, xamarin, android-service, lifecycle, android-event

I have an app which has a queue in the background to do something. I also have a service which shows and updates a notification in the notification-center about the progress of the queue (because it is not depending on a certain activity).

Notification be like: "there are 4 items left".

All works great except the app is destroyed (by the user and/or system).

I want to update the notification bevore the app or the service is closed (to something like "come back, you missed some items"). I know there is no "close"-event for an application and the "destroyed" event from the service is not called in this case.

I'm working with Xamarin.

What can I do to achive this? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @joeshi app closed in the sence(notifications will not update when ever the app closed?? ).

Comment: I dont know when to update the notification, or delete it

Comment: the service is closing?? .better run in separate process or use forgroundService

Comment: I tried this. But I need to know, when the user or the system closes my app. Is there no way?

Comment: tried with onDestroy()??;

Comment: Yes. But it is never called when I close the app from the "open-apps-list". So I think there is no way.. all searchin in the web gave me the same..

Comment: why your service is closing are you doing any overloaded work in the service?

Answer (score 1):

You can initiate your background service using Alarm Manager even if it is killed. I have faced the same problem when I had to update the user's current location. I set an infinite alarm which starts android service if its not started in every five minutes. You can give it a try.

Comment: This is the last resort =) I just wanted to ask if there is another "clean" solution to do this.. Thank you